# Subscript/superscript characters in rasterVis::levelplot strip labels

Tags: r, text, raster, lattice, rastervis

Can we include subscript/superscript characters in `rasterVis::levelplot` strip labels?

Consider the following `RasterStack`, `s`:

```
library(rasterVis)
s <- stack(replicate(2, raster(matrix(runif(9), 3))))
```

The default plot method for `Raster*` objects allows expressions to be passed to the `main` argument:

```
plot(s, main=expression(Something, Something[2]))
```

[image]

With `rasterVis::levelplot`, strip names are passed via the `names.attr` argument, but it seems these are coerced to `character` before eventually being passed to `lattice::levelplot` with `strip.custom(factor.levels = names.attr)`.

The result is:

```
levelplot(s, names.attr=expression(Something, Something[2]))
```

[image]

Short of modifying the source, is there a way to use expressions (or otherwise achieve subscript/superscript characters) in strip labels of `rasterVis::levelplot`?

Comment: The documentation fpr rasterVis::contourplot does not suggest htat the author expected an exprssion-object. I says "character" for the `names.attr` parameter. And it turns out to be a flipping S4 method, so it will take a lot of digging to figure out what's actually going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might think that `rasterVis::levelplot` was using the code of `lattice::levelplot` and to an extent that turns out to be the case, but a bunch of data transformation occurs first. The S4-method cannot be seen by using the signature with x="RasterBrick", but rather needs x="Raster".

```
showMethods("levelplot", classes="RasterStack", includeDefs=TRUE)

getMethod("levelplot", signature=c(x="Raster", data="missing"))
```

That shows that the code constructing the strips is defined as:

```
    ....
            strip = strip.custom(factor.levels = names.attr), 
    ....
```

I would have guessed that `factor.levels` would have been the correct parameter to pass an expression to. There is a coercion step that is causing the failure. So you need to hack the code to allow an expression to make it through. If I comment out the coercion with `as.character`:

```
        else {
         # names.attr <- as.character(names.attr)
         if (length(names.attr) != nlayers(object)) 
             stop("Length of names.attr should match number of layers.")
```

Using:

```
setMethod( "levelplot:   {
  function code
  },  signature= c(x="Raster", data="missing"))
```

And copy two unexported function from rasterVis to the the global environment I get success:

```
drawMargin <- rasterVis:::drawMargin
constructMargin <- rasterVis:::constructMargin
```

And pass the uncoerced expressions to 'factor.levels' via `names.attr`:

```
png(); print(levelplot(s, names.attr=expression(Something, Something[2])) );dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to dig around. I had found the method's source, and the coercion to character, but was hoping there might be a clever way to circumvent it (other than commenting it out). That said, your approach works fine, so I appreciate your post. Maybe @OscarPerpiñán might reconsider the `as.character` ;)

Comment: @jbaums  There's a github issue report: https://github.com/oscarperpinan/rastervis/issues

Comment: Good point, @Pascal... I was being lazy. Have posted an issue now.

Comment: Fixed now with this [commit](https://github.com/oscarperpinan/rastervis/commit/7d2faf6a77d1962362ee6bca8737ef3c686f9419). Thanks for reporting this issue.